# Capistrano deployment error at task create_release

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano

Good morning fellow developers !

Here I am for my very first post on Stackoverflow !

I have a problem deploying a Sinatra application, and can't figure out why it doesn't work, so I might need a little help from one of you.

When I run the following command

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

I get the following error (the config/deploy.rb file is created, along with the config/deploy/staging.rb) :

```
 INFO [864af525] Running /usr/bin/env git archive development | tar -x -C /var/www/mykio-admin/releases/20131224102759 on <our server address>
DEBUG [864af525] Command: cd /var/www/mykio-admin/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/mykio-admin/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive development | tar -x -C /var/www/mykio-admin/releases/20131224102759 )
DEBUG [864af525]    fatal: Not a valid object name
DEBUG [864af525]    
DEBUG [864af525]    tar: 
DEBUG [864af525]    Ceci ne ressemble pas à une archive de type « tar »
DEBUG [864af525]    
DEBUG [864af525]    tar: 
DEBUG [864af525]    Arrêt avec code d'échec à cause des erreurs précédentes
DEBUG [864af525]    
cap aborted!
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Nothing written
/home/babausse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
[...]
/home/babausse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:create_release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to run the following command to check if everything is ok

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy:check
```

I don't get any error and I find it weird, it's made to check if the deployment configuration is ok, so the deployment should be possible, and it's not.

Anybody here could have a clue about this error ?

Comment: post your capistrano recipe

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you might not have pushed your 'development' branch to your remote repository and git is failing trying to archive your local 'development' branch.

Comment: this fixed mine